# Is it possible to check whether hadoop cluster is yarn enabled using java?

Tags: java, hadoop

I know that how to enable Yarn in the cluster by providing the value of mapreduce.framework.name as yarn in the mapred.xml file. I just want to know via Java API whether it is possible to know that yarn is enabled or not when I know only fs.defaultFS.

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting the [YARN Web Services](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebServicesIntro.html) and decide based on whether you receive a response  or not and if you do what information it provides for your application,either error message or success.